# T-SQL to select row count from two tables, excluding duplicates

Tags: sql-server

So, I have 2 tables…. I need to get the combined row count from both, excluding any duplicates…

For example….

Table 1 has 20000 rows and Table 2 has 500 rows

There is 1 duplicate id that is in both table 1 and table 2, so the total row count should be 20,499….

This is what I have tried so far….

---

with cterc as

(SELECT COUNT(*) as rn

FROM Table_1 as t1

join Table_2 as t2 on t1.id <> t2.id)

SELECT SUM(rn) as totalrowNo

from cterc

---

Comment: `UNION` the `ID`s and then `COUNT`? `UNION ALL` the `ID`s and then `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following provide your expected count?

```
select count(*)
from (
  Select Id from Table_1
  union /* distinct values, union all doesn't distinct values */
  Select Id from Table_2
)t;
```